# Browserify Error: Parsing file, Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, reactjs, browserify

I am trying to use this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spin) with browserify.

When I run `$ browserify build/widget.js -o bundle.js`, I recieve the following error:

```
Error: Parsing file /Users/nir/browsewidget/node_modules/react-spin/src/main.js: Unexpected token (29:6)
    at Deps.parseDeps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:436:28)
    at fromSource (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:375:44)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:369:17
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:36:43)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at finishMaybe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:460:14)
    at endWritable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:469:3)
    at ConcatStream.Writable.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:436:5)
    at DuplexWrapper.onend (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:537:10)
    at DuplexWrapper.g (events.js:199:16)
```

Note: the file `build/widget.js` is not JSX, it has been built using the [JSX compiler](https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html).

Why would I be receiving unexpected token?

**Edit based on snozza's answer:**

I have installed `npm install reactify --save`.

Then I ran `% browserify -t reactify build/widget.js`
Which gave the `-bash: fg: %: no such job`

Then I tried `browserify -t reactify build/widget.js` 
, which gave:

```
Error: Parsing file /Users/nir/browsewidget/node_modules/react-spin/src/main.js: Unexpected token (29:6)
    at Deps.parseDeps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:436:28)
    at fromSource (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:375:44)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:369:17
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:36:43)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at finishMaybe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:460:14)
    at endWritable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:469:3)
    at ConcatStream.Writable.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:436:5)
    at DuplexWrapper.onend (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:537:10)
    at DuplexWrapper.g (events.js:199:16)
```

Here is a snippet of my `build/widget.js` as requested:

```
    var React =require('react');
    var Spinner = require('react-spin')

    var Loading = React.createClass({displayName: "Loading",
        render: function() {
            var spinCfg ={
              lines: 5 // The number of lines to draw
              , length: 5 // The length of each line
              , width: 42 // The line thickness
              , radius: 21 // The radius of the inner circle
              , scale: 1 // Scales overall size of the spinner
              , corners: 1 // Corner roundness (0..1)
              , color: '#000' // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
              , opacity: 0.25 // Opacity of the lines
              , rotate: 0 // The rotation offset
              , direction: 1 // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
              , speed: 1 // Rounds per second
              , trail: 60 // Afterglow percentage
              , fps: 20 // Frames per second when using setTimeout() as a fallback for CSS
              , zIndex: 2e9 // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
              , className: 'spinner' // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
              , top: '50%' // Top position relative to parent
              , left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
              , shadow: false // Whether to render a shadow
              , hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
              , position: 'absolute' // Element positioning
            };

            return React.createElement(Spinner, {config: spinCfg})
        }
    })

//...etc...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking through the main.js file of react-spin https://github.com/thomasboyt/react-spin/blob/master/src/main.js, it does indeed contain JSX syntax, namely:

```
return (
      <span ref="container" />
);
```

That is leading to the parse error when browserify is parsing that file.
You could use a transformer such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactify in conjunction with browserify to transform the JSX into vanilla JS.

**EDIT: Reactify example**

As it is a required node_module that also needs to be transformed, you will need to add the browserify/reactify transform option to the package.json of `react-spin`. Go to the `react-spin` folder and copy this into the package json, beneath `"main"`:

```
"browserify": {"transform": ["reactify"]},
```

Then try run the browserify command once again

Comment: I have updated my question based on your answer, take a look if you can.

Comment: I can't share everything, but I have added a snippet.

Comment: After applying the line to the package.json of react-spin I typed `browserify -t reactify build/widget.js` and  I get: `Error: Cannot find module 'react' from '/Users/nir/browsewidget/build'`

Comment: Disregard that, just had to `npm install react --save` as well. Thank you!